# How can I dynamically disable popover from a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have almost identical multiple divs on a page. They all have graphs inside I want some of them to have popovers when they are hovered.

I want to decide for each div if the popover is displayable or not. Is there a property that I can include inside options such as "diplay: false" ?

HTML

```
<div id="{{graph.id}}" data-ng-repeat="graph in graphs" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Parameters"></div>
```

JS

```
var options = {
    html: true,
    placement: 'top',
    trigger : 'hover',
    content: function() {
        return $('#info-chart-' + currentObj.id).html();
    }
}
$(currentObj.id).popover(options);
```

Comment: how to decide which div should have no popover?

Comment: @Alex That's what I am asking

Comment: Why not use an empty hover function in those where you don't want to display.

Comment: @brainmassage how should we know which of your divs should have a popover and which dont?! do you know specific ids of divs that shouldnt have a popover? how to decide?

Comment: You can also do something like if you don't want it to display then change the  display property of popover to none on hover.

Comment: you just shouldnt call the function on those which shouldnt have a popover.. jeez

Comment: @Alex I don't think he is calling popover though . He must be using bootstrap's default one.

Comment: @Maverick Can you give an example with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some class to those elements on which you don't want popup like **nopop** class.

```
<div id="{{graph.id}}" class="nopop" data-ng-repeat="graph in graphs" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Parameters"></div>
```

Now change the jquery code.

```
$(currentObj.id).not(".nopop").popover(options);
```

You can check here --> [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tudgmkf0/)